# CORS Error - Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing in Response Header (only from Spanish IPs)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-oauth, openid-connect

## Google Sign-In via OpenID Connect

For a web app I use *Google Sign-In via OpenID Connect*. It worked well for users all over Europe without any problems.

Since July **login from Spanish IPs is no longer possible** because it ends with a *CORS* error.

The reason for the *CORS* problem is that after a request with *"Origin"* in the request header, the response header did not contain the *'access-control-allow-origin'*.

The problem request is against the *jwks-uri* ("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs") from the Google Discovery Document.

The missing *'access-control-allow-origin'* in response header occurs only from requests from Spanish IPs. Europe-wide the response header contains the 'access-control-allow-origin'* .

The missing *'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'* in the Response Header can be viewed with curl:

> curl -v -H "Origin: https://bla.appspot.com" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

### Correct response outside Spain:

...
< x-xss-protection: 0
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
**< access-control-allow-origin: https://bla.appspot.com**
< access-control-expose-headers: date,content-encoding,server,content-length
< alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
< accept-ranges: none
...

### Incorrect response from Spanish IPs:

...
< x-xss-protection: 0
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< cache-control: public, max-age=24874, must-revalidate, no-transform
< age: 9060
< alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
< accept-ranges: none
...

Why does this only happen with Spanish IPs and how do I get a required "access-control-allow-origin" in a response header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I opened a case at Google Support that confirmed the fix today.**

*"...
The App Engine specialist confirmed that the issue was on our end and it was fixed. Can you check and confirm that from your end? 
..."*

In case of request of Spanish and French IPs against the
jwks-uri ("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs") 
an **access-control-allow-origin** will be delivered in the Response Header again.